# Javascript: Usability of curly brackets

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble understanding the use of outermost brackets `()` . I tried removing them but it didn't work. What are the they and how do I know more about them?

```
({ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 });

console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```

Anybody willing to shed some light is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `var` or `let` to declare the variables of destructuring assignment then it will work without `()`. You might be missing the declaration so it was not working for you.

```js
var { a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 };

console.log(a); // 10
console.log(b); // 20
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),

> Parenthesize the body of function to return an object literal
>   expression:
>
> ```
> params => ({foo: bar})
> ```

Also have a look at this example,

> Destructuring within the parameter list is also supported
>
> ```
> var f = ([a, b] = [1, 2], {x: c} = {x: a + b}) => a + b + c;
> f(); // 6
> ```

Hopefully, this helps to clear your doubt.